# How to implement Conditional required validation in angular forms?

Tags: javascript, angular, types, form-fields

If both fields don't have inputs then both can be optional. If firstname has input then set lastname as required. If lastname has input but firstname has no input then set firstname as **required**.

Set other field as required if one field has value and the other has not. Thank you.

So it's like if i am the user and there are two fields which is firstname and lastname. If i input data on firstname but lastname is empty then set the lastname as required (vice versa). Any idea ? thanks

**HTML**

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="24px" formGroupName="person">
  <div fxFlex fxLayout="row">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-4" fxFlex>
      <mat-label>Firsname</mat-label>
      <input matInput #firstname formControlName="firstname" trim  required/>
      <button type="button" mat-button   *ngIf="firstname.value"  matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"
      (click)="clearFieldFirstname()">
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex fxLayout="row">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-4" fxFlex>
      <mat-label>Lastname</mat-label>
      <input matInput #lastname formControlName="lastname" trim required/>
      <button type="button" mat-button   *ngIf="lastname.value"  matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"
      (click)="clearFieldLastname()">
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS CODE**

```
const personGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  firstName: [person.firstName, Validators.required],
  lastName: [person.lastName, Validators.required],
});

const formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  person: personGroup,
});

this.person.get("firstname").valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  const lastName = this.person.get("lastname");
  lastName.clearValidators();
  if (value && !lastName.value) {
    lastName.setValidators(Validators.required);
  }
  lastName.updateValueAndValidity({
    emitEvent: false
  });
});

this.person.get("lastname").valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  const firstName = this.person.get("firstname");
  if (value && !firstName.value) {
    firstName.setValidators(Validators.required);
  } else {
    firstName.clearValidators();
  }
  firstName.updateValueAndValidity({
    emitEvent: false
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the issue with this code you provided ?

Comment: it does not work

Comment: First of all remove remove [Validators.required] from 2nd and 3rd line as you want to keep both fields optional by default

Comment: @GopalZadafiya it does not work either Sir

Answer (score 2):

```
const personGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  firstName: [
    person.firstName,
    (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      // do your validation logic here:
      if (this.formGroup?.get('lastName').value) {
        if (!control.value) {
          return {required: true};
        }
      }
      // all is fine:
      return null;
    }
  ],
  lastName: [
    person.lastName,
    (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      if (this.formGroup?.get('firstName').value) {
        if (!control.value) {
          return {required: true};
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  ],
});
```

Comment: @MarkLatin stackblitz code provided by you is working as expected right?

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti , Im also after for a clean implementation , I am not confident with my stackblitz

Comment: @Mark , where does this formGroup came from Sir ?